# Zero cross detection with serial communication from Arduino to Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi3, python-3.5, arduino-uno

I'm new at python and i'm setting up my school project that it's going to detect the zero cross for trigger a PWM pulse so i'm using Arduino and Raspberry Pi 3.

I'm trying to read from serial port of the Arduino for read it in the Raspberry Pi, after that what i need is build an if conditional with that data that i recieved.

Arduino sends from serial port `ON` and `OFF` message with this code

```
const int inputPin = 2;

int value = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(inputPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop(){
  value = digitalRead(inputPin);  //digital read of pin

  //sends a message to serial port depending of the value read
  if (value == HIGH) {
      Serial.println("ON");
  }
  else {
      Serial.println("OFF");
  }
  delayMicroseconds(1000);
}
```

On Arduino serial read it shows continuously

```
OFF
ON
ON
ON
OFF
```

So on python i want to read those two values "ON" and "OFF" or at least one that `when it takes a OFF value` for example at the `next 1 ms` it `turn on PWM pulse`.

Something like:

```
if zerocross == OFF:
   pi.hardware_PWM(heat,200,dutycycle)
```

This is my python code for read the data from serial port:

```
import time

try:
    import serial
    arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', baudrate=9600, timeout=1.0)

    arduino.setDTR(False)
    time.sleep(1)
    arduino.flushInput()
    arduino.setDTR(True)

except (ImportError, serial.SerialException):

    import io

    class FakeArduino(io.RawIOBase):
        def readline(self):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            return b'sensor = 0\toutput = 0\r\n'

    arduino = FakeArduino()


with arduino:
    while True:
        try:
            line = arduino.readline()
            zerocross = line.decode('ascii', errors='replace')#, end=''
            if zerocross == OFF:
            print ('ok')

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Exiting")
            break
```

this is the out in the python shell

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/arduino python raspb.py", line 33, in <module>
    if zerocross == OFF:
NameError: name 'OFF' is not defined
```

I've already tried to convert the serial data into a string but i get "built-in method decode" when i try to print the value. Please if someone can show me some other methods i would appreciate it so much.

Comment: If the ON and OFF are coming as strings (or cast as a certain data type), you can not compare the way you are trying (variable value to variable value).  Your error is telling you that it is looking for OFF to be a variable (which is not defined).  Try 'OFF' and 'ON' (represented as strings) and see what happens . . .

Comment: The data from serial port comes as this

Comment: Did you try and cast it as a string?  Try this without quotes, you will get a similar error: print("Exiting"), You do not know there is not code running changing a 0 to the string OFF for printing, or 1 to ON for printing to the screen.  ON or OFF, more likely as 0 or 1 if it is coming across a port (those values are likely interpreted).  Try casting as a string "OFF" or 'OFF' and let me know what happens.  You are reading characters, that is either a string or an array of characters to work with depending on the language.

Comment: The data from serial port comes as a byte in the shell without the "decode" line:
```
b'OFF\r\n'
b'ON\r\n'
b'ON\r\n'
b'ON\r\n'
b'OFF\r\n'
....
```
I've been reading that the read from serial port comes as a byte data so with line.decode('ascii').

I will try to send it as a binary data as you said, changing it from the arduino code. I'll check it and tell you what happen.

Comment: the \r is a carriage return and the \n is a new line, both used as commands in working with a string output, the b is a byte which is really a hex representation of binary (apparently you can cast them with ASCII chars.  So in effect the b . . . try this change>> zerocross = line.decode('UTF-8'),zerocross should now be a string and then  and this change >> if zerocross == "OFF":, let me know how that goes for you

Comment: Ok i changed as the last comment you told me, and instead of using "ON" or "OFF" words i've only used 0 for off and 1 for ON but i get the same result. Then i change de type of decoding to UTF-8, the decoding is right but the conditional is still not identifying the value, this is the line >>> if zerocross = "1": print ('ON") for checking that it is detecting the difference between 0 an 1 but doesn't print anything, i've added an else conditional to look if the code does something after the "if zero cross = "1": saying else: print ('OFF') but it always goes to the else condition.

Comment: If you used the decode it should be a string now. zerocross = line.decode('UTF-8') and if zerocross == "OFF":, before your if block print(zerocross) and see what it is for testing purposes.